# com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir]

Tags: tiles

I am getting these Warning Msg in my Logger. I am using Log4j and Tiles too. Before using Tiles these were not comming. Below are the Warning logs:

```
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.info: 31 Detected container provider Struts XML configuration provider (struts.xml) needs to be reloaded.  Reloading all providers. 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.info: 31 Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.info: 31 Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.info: 31 Parsing configuration file [struts.xml] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.info: 31 Overriding property struts.i18n.reload - old value: false new value: true 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.info: 31 Overriding property struts.configuration.xml.reload - old value: false new value: true 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.info: 31 Loading global messages from ApplicationResources 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [struts.actionMapping] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [org.apache.catalina.jsp_file] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [org.apache.catalina.jsp_file] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [struts.valueStack] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 No configuration found for the specified action: 'userLogin.action' in namespace: '/jsp/login'. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value. 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [.freemarker.Request] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [.freemarker.RequestParameters] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [templateDir] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [theme] 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn: 45 Could not find property [fieldErrors]
```

Please help me on this. My Logger file size is increasing and it is making my logger not usable..???

Comment: Please help me on this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For removing these warnings just add below lines of code in your log4j.xml file:

```
<logger name="com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger">
    <level value="warn"/>
</logger>
```